# ViewModel Pattern in Java Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Has anybody used a pattern to manage the View Models in Java Framework?
By ViewModels I am referring to the objects I'm sending to the View or the JSP file. The code looks too bad if I build each of the component within the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should do things like return page and get the Obj from Service in controller.Don't close database,make a function in another Object to do.